# Can I use BlocBuilder on MaterialPage in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, material-design, themes, flutter-bloc, cubit

I must change theme in my app. I tried a lot of practices but I was undecided.

I used Cubit for this and I wrapped up MaterialPage with blocbuilder. Is this a correct approach? I tried this and saw that the child was not rebuilt. So the case didn't work the same as setstate.But I got the answer in someone's comment that if it is done like this, it behaves like a setstate. What is the best practice for change theme?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => Tema(),
        )
      ],
      child: BlocBuilder<Tema, bool>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Material App',
            theme: context.read<Tema>().state ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
            home: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const text(),
              ),
              body: const CryptoPage(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}



class Tema extends Cubit<bool> {
  Tema() : super(true);

  void temaDegistir() {
    emit(state ? false : true);
  }
}
```

Comment: this works but it would be easier of readers if you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: Please provide sample code.

Comment: @Uvais I added sample code.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I added sample code.

Comment: how you toggling between theme

Comment: @YeasinSheikh in body page with float button using context.read<Tema>().temaDegistir().

Comment: it works,  I;ve tested with it ,

Comment: Yes it works. I know. My question is "Is this a correct approach"?